# SQL Триггер после вставки добавить данные в другую таблицу

Tags: sql-server, триггер

как сделать в MS SQL SERVER триггер при добавление данных полей фамилия,имя,отчество переходило в отдельную таблицу в поле ФИО (все три столбца)

Comment: так все таки - mysql или ms sql?

Comment: ms sql server //

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать триггер AFTER INSERT - подробнее тут [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
Необходимые вам данные хранятся в таблице INSERTED - подробнее тут [MSDN2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Пример запроса на создание триггера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fio_tg ON fio
AFTER INSERT
as
insert into fio2 (fio)
select first+' '+middle+' '+last
from inserted;
```

Ссылка на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60fdd0fac99001e577fb450f42688ff0)